# Loading a combo box data source

Tags: c#, combobox, datasource

SO I am wanting to load a data source for a combo box with the use of a function that receives as a string the name of the data source it needs to load and then have it load it however I cannot get this to work as I think the program is simply trying to load the variable name rather that the data source it represents. Sorry if that's badly worded hopefully my code clears up what I mean.

This is how I am doing it now

```
    bool TeamPlayers(string teamName, ComboBox team)//Makes the players of the selected team available for selection as scorers
    {
        if (teamName == "Canada")
        {
            string[] players = {"Johny Moonlight", "DTH Van Der Merwe", "Phil Mackenzie" };
            team.DataSource = players;
        }
        else if (teamName == "New Zealand")
        {
            string[] players = {"Dan Carter", "Richie Mccaw", "Julian Savea" };
            team.DataSource = players;
        }
        else if (teamName == "South Africa")
        {
            string[] players = {"Jean de Villiers", "Bryan Habana", "Morne Steyn" };
            team.DataSource = players;
        }
        return (true);
    }
```

But I would like to do something more like this

```
    bool TeamPlayers(string teamName, ComboBox team)//Makes the players of the selected team available for selection as scorers
    {
        string[] Canada = {"Johny Moonlight", "DTH Van Der Merwe", "Phil Mackenzie" };
        string[] NZ = {"Dan Carter", "Richie Mccaw", "Julian Savea" };
        string[] RSA = {"Jean de Villiers", "Bryan Habana", "Morne Steyn" };
        team.DataSource = teamName;
        return (true);
    }
```

Where teamName will be either Canada,NZ or RSA.
Does anyone know of a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to achieve similar functionality

```
bool TeamPlayers(string teamName, ComboBox team)//Makes the players of the selected team available for selection as scorers
{
    Dictionary<string, string[]> teamNames = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

    teamNames.Add("Canada", new string[] { "Johny Moonlight", "DTH Van Der Merwe", "Phil Mackenzie" });
    teamNames.Add("New Zealand", new string[] { "Dan Carter", "Richie Mccaw", "Julian Savea" });
    teamNames.Add("South Africa", new string[] { "Jean de Villiers", "Bryan Habana", "Morne Steyn" });

    team.DataSource = teamNames[teamName];
    return (true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. Would I be able to do the same thing but with an image box?

Comment: @JulienPowell Yes you can

Comment: Sorry but could you clarify a bit as for obvious reasons im having trouble doing it

Comment: @JulienPowell You may want to post your code or raise another question, without which I may find it difficult to answer. Another question, because your code would not render well in the comments.

Comment: I intended to do that but im waiting for the 90 minute cooldown so I can post again.

Answer (score 1):

Make a Dictionary of team names.

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> teams = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

public void PopulateTeams()
{
    teams.Add("canada", new[] { "Johny Moonlight", "DTH Van Der Merwe", "Phil Mackenzie" });
    teams.Add("nz", new[] { "Dan Carter", "Richie Mccaw", "Julian Savea" });
    teams.Add("rsa", new[] { "Jean de Villiers", "Bryan Habana", "Morne Steyn" });
}
```

Usage of Dictionary:

```
private bool TeamPlayers(string teamName, ComboBox team)
{
    team.DataSource = null;
    if (teams.ContainsKey(teamName))
    {
        team.DataSource = teams[teamName];
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a dictionary like so:

```
dict<string, string[]> teamPlayers;
```

Key would be teamname, value would be players.

```
team.DataSource = teamPlayers[teamName];
```